# How to compare against multiple strings in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

For comparing an xml string value against multiple strings, I am doing the following.

```
<xsl:if test="/Lines/@name = 'John' or /Lines/@name = 'Steve' or /Lines/@name = 'Marc' " >
```

Can any one tell me, instead of using 'or' in the above case, how can I check whether a string is existing in an set of strings using xslt.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for three different solutions, two of them for XSLT 1.0. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Three ways of doing this:

1. **Use a pipe (or other appropriate character) delimited string**

...

```
 <xsl:template match=
  "Lines[contains('|John|Steve|Mark|',
                  concat('|', @name, '|')
                 )
         ]
  ">
     <!-- Appropriate processing here -->
 </xsl:template>
```

.2. **Test against an externally passed parameter**. If the parameter is not externally set, and we are using XSLT 1.0, the `xxx:node-set()` extension function needs to be used to convert it to normal node-set, before accessing its children

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <!-- externally-specified parameter -->
 <xsl:param name="pNames">
  <n>John</n>
  <n>Steve</n>
  <n>Mark</n>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="Lines">
  <xsl:if test="@name = $pNames/*">
     <!-- Appropriate processing here -->
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

.3. **In XSLT 2.0 compare against a sequence of strings**

```
 <xsl:template match="Lines[@name=('John','Steve','Mark')]">
     <!-- Appropriate processing here -->
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: @empo: Thanks. What do you mean by "really contracted"?

Comment: I meant "short" :) sorry for my english.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. (May be tomorrow only)

Comment: I get the error **Reference to variable or parameter 'pNames' must evaluate to a node list**.

Comment: +1, I tried the check using Pipe method, it worked fine... But the 2nd one didn't work properly :(

Any how Thank you :)

Comment: @User123343: You are welcome. For the second method you must be using an XSLT 1.0 processor. Also, you must use the correct `xxx:node-set()` extension function, exactly for your XSLT processor.

Answer (score 9):

XSLT 2.0 only: `<xsl:if test="/Lines/@name = ('John', 'Steve', 'Marc')">`

With XSLT 1.0 you can't write a literal expression representing a sequence of strings or a set of strings but if you know the literal values then you can construct a set of nodes e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:data="http://example.com/data"
  exclude-result-prefixes="data">

  <data:data xmlns="">
    <value>John</value>
    <value>Steve</value>
    <value>Marc</value>
  </data:data>

  <xsl:variable name="values" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/data:data/value"/>

  <xsl:template match="...">
     <xsl:if test="/Lines/@name = $values">..</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there any other way to do it in 1.0?

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. (May be tomorrow only)

Comment: +1 for the use of document('')/xsl:stylesheet instead of node-set()!

Answer (score 4):

Yep - I use substring - put all your name in a string - xsl:variable - then if contains true, the name is there

e.g.

```
 <xsl:variable name="months">**janfebmaraprmajjunjulaugsepoktnovdec</xsl:variable>


 <xsl:if test="contains($months,'feb')"> do stuff ...
```

Comment: @Bhaskar - I don't see why not. You'd need to adapt it, and probably add a separator character between the possible values, but it should work just as well for a list of names as for a list of months.

Answer (score 3):

XPath has a `some $x in (1,2,..) satisfies $x>10` expression that could be useful for this. See: http://www.java2s.com/Code/XML/XSLT-stylesheet/everyandsomeoperator.htm

Answer (score 1):

For space-separated words you can use `index-of(tokenize("list of allowed", "\s+"), "needle"))` or `match` to go with regular expressions, although I am pretty sure there is something smarter than this.

Comment: No, that's exactly what I would use when the list is a delimited string.

Answer (score 1):

Other possiblity:

**XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0)**

```
matches(/Lines/@name, 'John|Steve|Marc')
```

In **XSLT 1.0** you have the similar function `matches` provided by [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/index.html).

**Notice**

This is not *exact* match against the string, but a *regex* match, which in your case seems appropriate anyway.

Comment: The functx example is wrong -- it is XSLT 2.0 only -- please, correct.

Comment: @DImitre-Novatchev: thought FunctX working in XSLT 1.0 even if never tried before. What's the difference with XPath 2.0 functions then?