# XSLT: contains() function with multiple strings

Tags: xslt

I've got an XML in this vein:

```
<style name='Danger'/>
<style name='Danger_2'/>
<style name='Danger_3'/>
<style name='Warning'/>
<style name='Warning_2'/>
<style name='Warning_3'/>
<style name='Body'/>
```

I'm trying to process all styles whose name contains "Danger" or "Warning". 
Naive approach that doesn't work:

```
<xsl:template match="style[contains(@name, 'Danger|Warning')]">
```

I'm aware you can do this in XSLT 2.0 with exact matches:

```
"style[@name=('Danger','Warning')]"
```

Is there a solution for 'contains' matches?

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357166/how-to-compare-against-multiple-strings-in-xslt) has an interesting solution: 'Use a pipe (or other appropriate character) delimited string', but despite the use of 'contains' that only works for exact matches (so it'll match 'Danger' but not 'Danger_1').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With XSLT/XPath 2.0 and later there is the `matches` function (http://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/fn/matches.html) with regular expression support `style[matches(@name, 'Danger|Warning')]`.

Additionally you can also use `style[some $s in ('Danger','Warning') satisfies contains(@name, $s)]`, that is also possible with XSLT/XPath 2.0 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

`<xsl:template match="style[contains(@name, 'Danger') or contains(@name, 'Warning')]">`

Comment: I'd prefer a shorter solution if one exists (need to match 20 strings, not 2).