# How to match values in variable in predicate in XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have a working XSLT 2 or 3 process where I pass a single word string as a parameter into the XSL template. For this task I'm passing a surname which is used to find all `<person>` elements in multiple XML documents where it's child `<nL>` ,name last, element matches the parameter I've passed. This works but I'd like to modify my XPATH expression to be able to pass a comma separated parameter. For example, I can now pass surname="Johnson" but would like to be able to pass surname="Johnson,Johnston"

I'm using the latest Saxon processor in java. I invoke the transformation with

`java net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:all-sources.xml -xsl:xsl/index-person-param.xsl surname="Johnson"`

all-sources.xml is an XML formated list of other XML files.

I will only include a small section of my code unless more is needed. This is likely a simple XPATH issue that I just don't understand.

Currently before my template match I have this parameter declaration

`<xsl:param name="surname" as="xs:string" required="yes"/>`

then I find all the matching `<person>` elements with the following variable

`<xsl:variable name="nameMatch" select="document(/files/file/@filename)//person[nL = $surname]"/>`

This works when the $surname variable is a one-word string. How could I modify the predicate above so that $surname can contain two or more words separated by a comma?

I've tried several alterations using `tokenize()` and `contains()` but I've still not found a working solution.
Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Have you tried any of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357166/how-to-compare-against-multiple-strings-in-xslt

Comment: I searched through the thread you provided and found a solution. I've changed the `select="document(/files/file/@filename)//person[nL = $surname]"` to `select="document(/files/file/@filename)//person[matches(nL,$surname)]"`  which gives me the desired result. Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep `<xsl:param name="surnames" as="xs:string" required="yes"/>` then use `tokenize` to create a sequence of strings with e.g. `<xsl:param name="surname-seq" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize($surnames, '\s*,\s*')"/>` and then compare `nL = $surname-seq`.

Or change the parameter to be a sequence of strings with e.g. `<xsl:param name="surname" as="xs:string*" required="yes"/>`, then, on the command line you need to make sure you use e.g. `?surname="'foo','bar'"`. You will have to test which combinations of quotes work, the question mark `?surname` indicates the value is an XPath expression, it then depends on the command shell you use what you need to make sure you pass a complete expression to Saxon.

Comment: Martin, in addition to the solution I found in the thread Lesiak provided, I tested your first suggestion and got the working and desired solution also. Thanks again for taking the time teach.  -Michael